# Databricks SQL syntax for previous six months in where statement

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to look for data in the last six months in the where statement of a SQL query in Databricks, but I'm having a lot of issues with the syntax.

Right now I have:

```
Select * from table
where datediff(add_months(date_column, -6), date_column) = 1
```

The query doesn't throw an error, but returns no results.

Comment: so if i am getting you right  you have 01-01-2023 and you remove 6 m0nths lets say 01-07-2022 and you expect a number 1 for the difference? the result of the datediff would be around 180 and can never be 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're expecting the wrong thing from datediff. Datediff tells you the number of days between two dates. In your case, you're comparing your date_column to your date_column - 6 months. That's always going to be 6 months or ~180 days.

Try this.

```
WHERE date_column > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_DATE())
```

AKA, where your date column is greater than the current date minus 6 months.

Comment: Is CURRENT_DATE() a function I need to define myself?

Comment: No. CURRENT_DATE() returns today's date. If you do select DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_DATE()), it should return the date 6 months ago today.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `interval` keyword.

```
where `date` >= date_trunc('MONTH', now()) - interval 7 month
```